# How to store in a variable a Glade widget?

Tags: c, gtk, glade

:) Is there a way to store in a variable a widget from a Glade file so I can use that variable later in a Gtk+ function such as gtk_spin_button_get_value (variable that contains spinbutton object)? Thanks a lot in advance! :'D

For context, in a struct there are statements like this:

`GtkWidget *window_Option;`  so I can save them in an object with this line:

`factory->window_Option = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object  (builder, "window_Option"));`

The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to get the value of a spinbutton like this:

`value.array_Options[0] = gtk_spin_button_get_value (factory->spinbutton_time_unit)`;`

but it is not working. I know it's because of gtk_spin_button_get_value expects a spinbutton object and I'm providing it a widget object, but I don't know how to transform it into one or obtainig from the glade file the GtkSpinButton object I'm looking for. :/

Comment: OK I figured it out! xD Thank to God. :D It was an issue of casting or something like that. By means of a casting macro the issue  is solved. It should be like this: "  factory->spinbutton_time_unit = (GtkSpinButton*)gtk_builder_get_object  (builder, "spinbutton_time_unit");   " The magic xD is in the (GtkSpinButton*) thing. :)

Comment: please post this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out! xD Thank to God. :D It was an issue of casting or something like that. By means of a casting macro the issue is solved. It should be like this:

```
factory->spinbutton_time_unit = (GtkSpinButton*)gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "spinbutton_time_unit");
```

The magic xD is in the `(GtkSpinButton*)` thing. :)